# spotlight search in the application

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, spotlight

Is that possible for spotlight search of iphone to take the contents of my application and show as search results ?

If yes how to accomplish ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible with the current SDK.

Comment: is that possible with iOS 4.0 ?

Comment: Nope, this isn't in iOS 4 either.

Comment: Thanks. Can you get me any apple docs which says that this is not possible ?

Comment: There are no Apple docs which say that it isn't possible, but the absence of any API documentation relating to integrating Spotlight into apps is a fairly good indication that you can't do it ;-)